# show path of an image (selected from internal storage to appear on imageview) on texteview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-image

I am displaying two images on two imageviews, one with request code 101 and another with 102

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 101);// change request
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Select Picture"), 102); // change request code
```

and i want their path name for example, img1.jpg or path for example, storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/img1.jpg to be displayed on 2 textviews which i have for that i am writing following code but it is force stopping the app

```
if (requestCode == 101) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        File file = new File( getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri));
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
        iv.setTag(path);
        String impath = (String) iv.getTag();
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        myText.setText(impath);
    }
    else if(requestCode == 102){
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView2);
        File file = new File( getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri));
        String path1 = file.getAbsolutePath();
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path1));
        iv.setTag(path1);
        String impath = (String) iv.getTag();
        TextView myText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        myText1.setText(impath);
    }
public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

The error log is saying,

```
Process: select_image_demo.coderzheaven.com.selectimage, PID: 11845
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=102, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:42038 flg=0x1 }} to activity {select_image_demo.coderzheaven.com.selectimage/select_image_demo.coderzheaven.com.selectimage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4090)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4133)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1534)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:262)
                  at select_image_demo.coderzheaven.com.selectimage.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:84)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6979)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4086)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4133) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1534) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Comment: Can you print Error Log.

Comment: Are you asking for permissions or not ?

Comment: heisen-berg i am able to show selected images on imageview successfully. its the path i am having problem with

Comment: I think error is in this line TextView myText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        myText1.setText(impath);